# Learning .net`s basics with SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008

How to begin studying `.net and SQL Server communication`, any good tutorial that had helped you to learn both, (I am refering how to communicate them)??

I have installed `SQL Server management 2008`, and now I would like to use `.net` to start communicating both .net and SQL Server.

What steps must be followed to achieve this...

- You start Visual Studio 2008, and make a routine, a class or... to connect to SQL Server...
- Do you have a simple example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a beginner you may benefit from learning Entity Framework. You may prefer to go the route of classic SQL server ADO.Net SqlConnections.

Entity Framework provides a really simple way for you to connect, retrieve and manipulate the data in your database.

Tutorial here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399182.aspx

Comment: Do you really think the Entity Framework is a good place to start for a beginner? Seems like that would be way to abstact and would be confusing . . . maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: I recently taught someone how to use it in 2 hours. They picked it up so well and they have absolutely no SQL experience.

Comment: I was thinking more the lack of .net experience.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to understand what's going on, check out [Ado.Net](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article103.aspx)

[This tutorial](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson01.aspx) seems to do a decent job of starting with the basics of Ado.Net and moving on to how to actually use it.

After you get that done, you might take a look at an ORM such as Entity Framework or NHibernate.  But I think you should understand the basics before jumping straight to an ORM.

Answer (score 0):

To start with the basics, you should look at using a datareader. That's a pretty fundamental way to communicate with a database server. See [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) (scroll down to the examples section) to get started.

For updates, see the [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery example in the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't gone through the official ASP.NET [step-by-step overview](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1) already, Step 4 deals with databases and so you may want to take a quick look.  It's pretty introductory but should get you started.

If you're a A/V learner like me, though, I definitely recommend [lynda.com](http://lynda.com).  It's a really good video tutorial service that includes both ASP.NET and SQL Server courses.  Some of the segments are free but, for just $25/month, it's a pretty good deal, especially if you intend to dive in and devote some time to this.

Best of luck!